# How to remove one particular value in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

```js
$(document).on("click","#Id",function(){
 var data = [
   { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
   { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
   { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" },
   { value: "AR", label: "Arkansas" },
   { value: "UT", label: "Utah" },
   { value: "VT", label: "Vermont" },
   { value: "VA", label: "Virginia" },
   { value: "WI", label: "Wisconsin" },
   { value: "WY", label: "Wyoming" }
  ];

$("#Id").autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: data,
  select: function( event, ui ) 
  {
    alert(ui.item.label);
  },
})
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) 
{
  if (item.label != "Virginia") {
    return $( "<li>" )
      .append( "<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.label + "</a>" )
      .appendTo( ul );
  }
};
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="Id">
```

This is my sample code if i use **Virginia** am getting empty line but i need the output to be blank.
can anyone solve my issue and provide me an solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Id").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem =  function( ul, item ) 
   {
    if(item.desc != "test"){
     return $( "<li>" )
     .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
     .appendTo( ul );
    }
   };
```

instead of `uiAutocomplete` use `ui-autocomplete`

Comment: @vinothkumar- could you please try with this?

Comment: simply try calling `$("#Id").data("ui-autocomplete")` directly. If it doesn't work then can its possible for you to put it in fiddle or code snippet so that I can take a look at it? It will be easier to fix it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `data` on `#Id`. It looks like its stored under `autocomplete`.

[image: autocomplete data]

so, if you have already called

```
$("#Id").autocomplete({
   source: data,
   etc : etc
});
```

then you can call:-

```
$("#Id").data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    if (item.value != "test") {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
};
```

or you can instantiate and set `_renderItem` like :-

```
 $("#Id").autocomplete({
    source: data
  }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    if (item.value != "test") {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
  };
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like different versions of jQueryUI store *autocomplete* under `data` differently, as your snippet compared to the version I used are different (`autocomplete` vs `ui-autocomplete`).

The issue with the *empty line*, is a border around the `ul`. Where the autocomplete thinks is has a value to show, but as you are saying not to render the only value in the autocomplete list then the `ul` still has the border. By removing the border around the `ul` will *fix* this. See the snippet below:-

```js
var data = [{
  value: "AL",
  label: "Alabama"
}, {
  value: "AK",
  label: "Alaska"
}, {
  value: "AZ",
  label: "Arizona"
}, {
  value: "AR",
  label: "Arkansas"
}, {
  value: "UT",
  label: "Utah"
}, {
  value: "VT",
  label: "Vermont"
}, {
  value: "VA",
  label: "Virginia"
}, {
  value: "WI",
  label: "Wisconsin"
}, {
  value: "WY",
  label: "Wyoming"
}];

$("#Id").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert(ui.item.label);
    },
  })
  .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    if (item.label != "Virginia") {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
  };
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="Id">
```

Comment: data('autocomplete ')
I have used this code,i didn't get any errors but my condition is not satisfied and data('autocomplete ') is not working

Comment: try calling `$("#Id").data()` from the console like the image.